# Help with Laser MPE calculation

Tags: safety, laser

I am building a laser room and I'm basically trying to calculate the maximum time of laser radiation to they eye before causing any harm. I found that to be **7 seconds** but I would very much appreciate if someone familiar with this topic can confirm that my calculations are accurate.

The lasers I use are green ones @352nm 50mW.
Based on the MPE and coefficient tables, the formula for Hmpe = C1 J/m^2  = 5.6 x 10^3 x (t^0.25) J/m^2 = 5.6 x 10^3 x (7^0.25) J/m^2 = **9.1 x 10^ 3 J/m^2**

In terms of irradiance obtained after dividing by t = 7s:

Empe = 1.3 W/m^2

Now, from [here](https://researchsafety.uchicago.edu/sites/researchsafety.uchicago.edu/files/uploads/Laser%20MPE%20and%20NHZ%20Calculations.pdf) "considering the limiting aperture of they eye in the visible region, 7mm,  then
the area over which the visible radiation will be viewed is π/4×0.7^2
= 0.385 cm2 = **3.85 * 10^-5 m^2** "

, the maximum power to avoid harm due to eye exposure is:

3.85 * 10^-5 * 1.2 * 10^3 W = 0.05W =**50mW** which is my lasers's output power.

You think this calculation is accurate?

Thank you in advance, 
Dimitris

Comment: Don't mess around with your eyes, the best limit is 0 seconds...

Comment: I agree but I still need to calculate safety levels. Thanks

Comment: Read the laser data sheet, take note what category of laser it is classified as and look up the safety precautions for that classification.

Comment: Get a pair of safety glasses designed to block the wave length of your laser.

Comment: @Tyler, but what o.d. do they need? Not all laser safety goggles are alike, even blocking the same wavelength.